# how to loop multiple arrays in react native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am actually want to iterate a collection in firestore which contains multiple documents, and i want to return the doc that contain field uid equal of my uid.

that's the data in firestore:

```
const { user } = this.props ;
console.log("getting user data: ", user )
```

[image: result on console]

that's my code:

```
render() {
   const auth = this.props.auth;
   console.log("getting user id: ", auth.uid);

   const userData = user.map((item)=>(
      (item.uid) = (auth.uid)
        ? <Text color="white" size={28} style={{ paddingBottom: 8 }}>
               { item.displayName } </Text>
        : <Text color="white" size={28} style={{ paddingBottom: 8 }}> Error 
          </Text>
      )
    );
return (

              <Block style={styles.profileTexts}>
                  {userData}
              </Block>
   )
}
const mapStateToProps = ( state ) => {
  console.log("state firebase",state);
  return{
    auth: state.firebase.auth,
    user: state.firestore.ordered.users,
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    signOut: () => dispatch(signOut()),
  }
}

export default compose(
   connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
   firestoreConnect([
       { collection: 'users'},
   ]))(Profile)
```

But i got this error:
"TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'o.map')"

Answer (score 0):

inside your map you are using assignment operator instead of comparison  operator.

if you just want to return an item which is same as `auth.uid` use a filter instead

Create a function which returns the `item.uid === auth.uid`

```
  userFn = () => {
      const {user} = this.props;
      const authUser = user.filter(item => {
          return item.uid === auth.uid
      })
     if (authUser.length>1){
         return <Text>{authUser[0].displayName}</Text>
     }
     else return <Text>Error</Text>
  }
```

then inside return statement

```
  return (
      <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center'}}>
          {this.userFn()}
      </View>
  );
```

Comment: mathiew same problem !

Comment: thnx for replying, in fact inside the return statement i change it to `{this.userFn}` because it rendering an error when i let it with parenthesis **this.userFn is not a function**, but it returns null even not displaying **Error**.
when i console log it, it shows this: `[Function userFn]`

Comment: did code worked after removing parenthesis? it worked for me with parenthesis

Comment: yes the code worked without parenthesis, but this function returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You use `user` in render() method, but I don't see where did you get them?
I think this can fix the problem.

```
render() {
   const auth = this.props.auth;
   console.log("getting user id: ", auth.uid);


   const user = this.props.user // <=== add this line
   const userData = user.map((item)=>(
   ...
```

Comment: actually when i add that line, it shows me **undefined**